# Subset Sum: Ruby with ".combination"

Tags: ruby, arrays, combinations

**Details of the problem:** To find if any combination of the array adds to the largest number found in the array.

**Here are the steps I am trying to implement:**

1. Extract the largest number from the array
2. Create a new array of
   all the potential combinations that could be added by using
   `.combination`
3. Test to see if any of these combinations equals the largest number in the original array.

**Status:** So far, I am just receiving an unexpected `end` error for the last `end` in the code. (I have found different answers online on how to solve the subset sums problem in Ruby, but would like to figure out how to solve it using the logic I have used so far.)

Any help would be great!

```
def subset_sum(sums)
    largest_number = subset_sum.sort.reverse[0]
    array_without_largest = subset_sum.sort.reverse[1..-1]
    full_combination = []
    i = 0
    while i <= array_without_largest.length
        full_combination = full_combination + array_without_largest.combination(i).to_a.to_s
        i += 1
    end

    j = 0
    while j <= full_combination.length
        return true if full_combination[j].inject { |sum, x| sum + x} == largest_number
            j += 1
        end
    end
    return false
end

puts subset_sum(1,2,3,4,10)
puts subset_sum(-1,-3,3,9,8)
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code.  From an efficiency standpoint, you don't need to sort the array to find the largest element.  You also don't need to sort it twice.  Next, `full_combination` is an array, but then you add a string to it?  The unexpected `end` is the one just below `j += 1`.  Above that you have an inlined `if`.  Inline `if`s should not have a matching `end`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
def any_subset_adds_to_max?(array)
  sub_array = array - [array.max]
  every_combination = (1..sub_array.length).flat_map { |n| sub_array.combination(n).to_a }
  every_combination.any? { |combination| combination.reduce(:+) == array.max }
end

[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 10],
  [-1, -3, 3, 9, 8]
].map { |test_array| any_subset_adds_to_max? test_array } # => [true, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest example of the code that I could do while maintaining the originality. It works and I appreciate the help!

```
def subset_sum(sums)

  largest_number = sums.max
  array_without_largest = sums - [largest_number]
  full_combination = []

  array_without_largest.size.times do |i|
    full_combination << array_without_largest.combination(i+1).to_a
  end
  full_combination.flatten!(1)

  full_combination.size.times do |i|
    return true if full_combination[i].inject(:+) == largest_number
  end

  false
end
```